# How to use complex data structures to populate a div or table in JavaScript & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need help understanding the best way to manipulate a JavaScript data structure (if you call it that?). I come from a Perl background and am trying to iterate through a JavaScript data structure to update a div (or table) on the fly. Currently I'm just making the data a variable (data) to get going. once I have that sorted then I will use jquery's ajax methods to get the data as a json object on the fly. It's my understanding that the data structure I'm currently generating is the same thing I would get if it were json?? if not then I guess thats another question..

I have searched many times for such a tutorial but they are all close but haven't found one that meets my needs...

I would like to in the future be able to re-order the array and repopulate the #data_table div so part of my question is: is this even the best way to represent the data? Then I want to update just one part of the array like a companies phone number or add a person then redraw the div from this updated array...

The end result to the user could look like:

Company: 99 Beans, Auckland, Ph: 360499
  People:
    Matt, 6471
    Christiaan, 6472
    Michelle, 6473
    Judy, 6474

Company: ....
* Next company and so forth..

My code so far is like this (except I have 500+ entries in the data array and only 2 here):

I have taken some of this code from another question I found here and tried to make it work for my type of structure..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var r = new Array();

var data= [
{
  "id":"6477",
  "c":"99 Beans",
  "ci":"Auckland",
  "p":"09 360499",
  "co":[
        {"id":"6471","c":" NZ", "n":"Matt" },
        {"id":"6472","c":" NZ", "n":"Chrstiaan" },
        {"id":"6473","c":" NZ", "n":"Michelle" },
        {"id":"6474","c":" NZ", "n":"Judy " },
        {"id":"6475","c":" NZ", "n":"Kate  " },
        {"id":"6476","c":" NZ", "n":"Unknown Person" }
       ]
},
{"id":"7145", "c":"A1 Ltd", "ci":"Te Puke ","p":"06 870090",
  "co":[{"id":"7145","c":" NZ", "n":"Alan" }
   ]
   },
];

// this alert used to work, when I had the data as an array of arrays so there must be a problem with how I'm referencing it or my data structure is wrong??
alert (data.length + " companies" );//+ data[455].co[0].n);

  var j = -1;
    for (var key=0, size=data.length; key<size; key++) {
     // first div 
      r[++j] ='<div>';
      r[++j] = data[key].id;
      r[++j] = ' - ';
      r[++j] = data[key].c;
      r[++j] = ' - ';
      r[++j] = data[key].p;
      r[++j] = '<br />';
     //inner div 

   var k = -1 ;
    for (var key1=0, size1=data[key].d.length; key1<size1; key1++) {
      r[++j] ='<div>';
      r[++j] = data[key].d.[key1].n + ' - ' + data[key].d.[key1].c + ' - ';
      r[++j] = '</div>';
   }  

      r[++j] = '</div>';
    } 

  $('#data_table').html(r.join('')); 

});

</script>

<div id="data_table"></div>
```

Comment: Can someone please tell me though why in my example the alert isn't working, I'm sure if I can understand that part the rest should be more straight forward...

Comment: Ahh, I see it's in my inner for loop is causing it to fail... so I need some help accessing those inner pieces.. Incase you're wondering why all the effort and I don't have a server side table generated, it's becuase there are ov 1000 rows of people assigned to over 500 companies and my client wants a big list which they can edit on the fly!!

Comment: Your code is not working because of a syntax error in `data[key].d.[key1].n`., which is invalid syntax. (it should be `data[key].d[key1].n`, I suppose. Use the Firebug extension ofr Firefox to detect this kind of issues that would otherwise go unnoticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "rendering an JSON object to HTML", you may want to have a look at [`jQuery.template()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) which allows to render pieces of HTML with a template syntax. I have never used it so I do not know how well it can perform with very big lists... (also note that it is still in beta)

**UPDATE**

Here is a working example (it might not be optimal or anything) but you should see the general idea ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/tsimbalar/A9uYP/

**UPDATE 2 for sake of completeness and traceability**

There was a syntax error in the original code which prevented the `alert()` from executing (and all following code).
See comment :

> Your code is not working because of a syntax error in
>   `data[key].d.[key1].n.`, which is invalid syntax. (it should be `data[key].d[key1].n`, I suppose. Use the Firebug extension ofr Firefox  to detect this kind of issues that would otherwise go unnoticed.

After fixing this typo, it is easy to iterate over the contents of the object using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) as mentioned by catalpa in another answer. You can then build HTML elements (i.e. [`$("<div/>")`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)) and append them to existing items of the page with [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) .  (see the fiddle about that part)

Comment: This is really cool to know thanks, I am looking at using it along with catalpa's answer!! (can't vote you up as I don't have any points yet)

Comment: and yes, your answer is the best that answers my needs of getting the iteration part correct thanks!! I guess your example code will stay at your link? any need to paste it here?

Comment: nope, jsfiddle seems to be the "de facto" standard way of sharing executable HTML/CSS/JS code snippets on stackoverflow (+ jsFiddle handles versionning of snippets and I assume it will remain there as long as jsFiddle lives). I'll paste a part of it for completeness (but this is very similar to catalpa's answer)

Answer (score 3):

JSON's representation in Javascript is a javascript object.

```
var json = {
  my_property: 2,
  another_property: 'string!'
}
```

You can then fetch properties with `json.my_property` or `json['my_property']` (which is nice if you don't know what exactly you are fetching, you can do `var something = 'something-the-user-selected'; json[something]`).

So, with jQuery, you would so something like this:

```
var json = {}; // get this from the server using $.AJAX() or $.getJSON()
$("#my_table").append("<tr><td>" + json.my_property + "</tr></td");
```

Or, if you got an array of, say, tweets, you should iterate over them, maybe with [underscore's each](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), [jQuery's each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) or plain old `for (var i = 0; i < json.tweets.length; i++)`.

Comment: Thanks, what you have explained makes sense, however I would like to know specifically how I do this using my data structure I've created above, it has arrays of hashes with arrays in it in places... I want to iterate over it and there will be loops inside loops.. I am unsure if I even have the syntax correct :(

Comment: Don't write perl in javascript, write javascript. Use the language idioms. I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but if you just want to populate a table or a div this is really over complicated.

Comment: sure, I don't think I'm writing Perl ;) I am wanting to iterate over the data structure I have stated above. it's to dynamically fill up a table (or Div) and also will be used to edit a particular item and then update the table.. So firstly, I need to know if the data structure I have made is correct syntactically as the alert doesn't alert ;)

Comment: +1 for the alternatives about iteration with/without js frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you are referring to is JSON.

With jQuery you can easily iterate your data structure with .each() and treat the returned value as an object with the attributes defined.

Here is a sample making the an Ajax call that will build your JSON object and iterating:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MySite/MyResource",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.length > 0){
                    $(data.d).each(function(){$('#mytable').append("<tr><td>Company: " + this.c + "</td></tr>");});
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                // do something appropriate
            }
        });
```

If you are looking to iterate farther then you can continue to call .each()

If data is your JSON value, this will format your specified string. (You'll have to JSONify your string to create it as the actual JSON object)

```
data.each(function(){ 
  $('#mydiv').append('Company: ' + this.c + ', ' + this.ci + ', Ph: ' + this.p + ' People: ');
  this.co.each(function(){$('#mydiv').append(this.n + ', ' + this.id);});
});
```

Comment: ok, the edit is more along what I'm looking for.. am having trouble going through the iterate further part...

Comment: You can continue iterate the structure as you come along your next level arrays.

Comment: If you are still having trouble visualizing your string as an object, pull it up in Firebug and you'll be able to see it as a fully nested object, and you can manipulate in console.

Comment: hah, great, I can see it's ok, it is the code in the inner for loop which is wrong, I'm trying the jQuery each method which is easier to read although I'm also looking for the quickest option on the CPU front which I'll test myself I guess..

Comment: and found the code syntax issue thanks to tsimbalar ... `data[key].d[key1].n` and not `data[key].d.[key1].n`

Comment: Thanks both your answers and tsimbalar's have helped I used parts of code from both, yours the ajax stuff and tsimbalar with the iteration parts (I couldn't get your version to work, but not your fault, the template method tsimbalar said is just perfect for my needs!)

Answer (score 0):

[handlebars](http://www.handlebarsjs.com/) js templating is far better than jquery template and can be used for rendering complex json objects in html